# how to run php code in string got form db?

Tags: php

how to run php code in string got form db?
I want to save some template snippets in db.then use db to require these snippets.how to do?
sometimes I store html code in db ,then echo these snippets easily when got from db . but sometiems I want to let some php code stored in db. so I no need to inlude static php but only using db snippet. but thest codes from db are html+php , when php only can echo them as str.

```
<?php 

    $name='linjuming';

    // get $part_code from db
    $part_code='<div class="hello"><?php echo $name ?></div>';

    // how to output:
    //<div class="hello">linjuming</div>
    echo $part_code;

?>
```

Comment: You are looking for [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), but as the docs say **its use is discouraged**. And you would have to parse the `<?php ?>` parts manually to feed them into `eval`.

Comment: you really need to explain better, or your question will be closed.

Comment: Please make your question more clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're asking for how to actually use the database. If you are, then that question isn't suitable for stack overflow. Also not sure if you want to directly parse PHP from a string (which is bad practice as it opens all sorts of security flaws). Your question confuses me as the code you've pasted says you're trying to just output a string as part of the div.

If you mean you just want to output that string in the div, then your code has php tags nested within php... Which is not how php works.

`$part_code="<div class=\"hello\">$name</div>";`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

    $name='linjuming';

    // get $part_code from db
    $part_code='<div class="hello">'.$name.'</div>';

    // how to output:
    //<div class="hello">linjuming</div>
    echo $part_code;

?>
```